# what file do i need to install murrine?

Tags: gnome, themes

I REALLY REALLY want to make my windows look "glassy" in gnome. I am trying to install the murrine engine from here http://ftp.acc.umu.se/pub/GNOME/sources/murrine/0.90/
But i have NO IDEA which file I need? can somebody please help me!?

im following these instructions http://www.unixmen.com/how-to-install-murrine-and-aurora-gtk2-engines-in-ubuntu/ but i have no idea what the engine file should look like? and also the ./configure command doesnt ex

Answer (score 1):

`sudo apt-get install gtk2-engines-murrine`will install the Murrine Engine.

`apt-cache search gtk2-engines*` will show you the available GTK 2 engines.

Comment: Thank you! 
Now i should be able to find this in my app folder? cause nothing is popping up

Comment: No, that's not an "app" it's a Theme engine, Themes that require Murrine will load it.

Comment: I'm sorry i dont understand...for example, i have the A-New-Hope theme that says it requires the murrine engine. There is a file called configure (in the theme) so now when i double click on it shouldnt i be able to open it using the theme engine that i just installed?

Comment: No that configuration file loads a configuration script for the Theme, it has nothing to do with murrine. I suggest you either search for or open a new question asking what are and how do theme engines work, you seem to be confusing things here.